# Sorting a string list with numbers on numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list which looks like this:

```py
mylist = ['item_11', 'item_0', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'item_9', 'item_10', 'item_none']
```

I want to sort it on the numbers, but starting with "item_none", so the result will look like this:

```py
['item_none', 'item_0', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'item_9', 'item_10', 'item_11']
```

I found a way which works for me, but it uses two list comprehensions to rename "item_none" to "item_-1" and back. I was wondering whether there is a more elegant way to do this? Thanks for any suggestions.

```py
newlist = ['item_-1' if 'none' in x else x for x in mylist]
newlist.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1]))
finallist = ['item_none' if '-1' in x else x for x in newlist]
```

Comment: You could write a key function that parsed `None` to `float("-inf")` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the key to `-1` if `none` is there in the list

```
In [8]: mylist = ['item_11', 'item_0', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'item_9', 'item_10', 'item_none']

In [9]: mylist.sort(key=lambda x: -1 if x.split("_")[-1] == "none" else int(x.split('_')[-1]))

In [10]: mylist
Out[10]: ['item_none', 'item_0', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'item_9', 'item_10', 'item_11']
```